# Regular expression for filtering similar characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to construct a regular expression to implement the following restriction:

> The value may be of any length, but may not contain similar letters/numbers which may cause confusion when printed. E.g., 1 (the numeric), I (an upper-case Latin i) and l ( a lower case Latin L) look similar; there may be other such examples

I've tried a few things but can't get it to work, any help would be much appreciated: thanks.

For example: I could have `Linux1` but not `LINUX1` or `linux1`

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer; hope it's true to what you want to do. Do you **need** a regular expression solution for this?

Comment: Yes, sorry maybe I should have been more clear: This is for a training exercise and not for practical use :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that regular expressions are the way to go here, but if you really need to, you would probably need to handle them on a case by case basis: `(1I)|(I1)|([Ii][Ll])|([Ll][Ii])`. So if the regex will match, you will have to reject the string. A working example of the regular expression can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/wJ6zH7/3).

As per your comments, you could try to use something like so: `(1.*I)|(I.*1)|([Ii].*[Ll])|([Ll].*[Ii])`. A working regex can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/wJ6zH7/4). This regular expression will also check *between* values which are deemed similar.

Comment: Thank you; however perhaps I should have been more similar: I need to reject the string in all cases if a pair of these rejected characters are present:

For example, your solution rejects 1I, however doesn't reject 1fdsafsI

Any ideas?

(I think I heard of a lookahead? Not sure if that could be useful here)

Comment: @Jackhardcastle: Can you please provide information on why you would want to reject `1fdsafsI`?

Comment: It's for a college assignment; they've provided me with a Regex tester PHP file and asked me to come up with solutions for each limitation, this limitation is passed into a preg_match() and then evaluated and passed/failed

It's not for practical purposes, however educational.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle: I see. However, what I meant was what *rules* did you apply which made you decide that `1fdsafsI` was not valid. Was it because it started and ended with characters which are deemed to be similar?

Comment: Oh; my bad, and yes because it contains a 1, it should not be able to contain an I (or a lowercase L), if that makes sense? It's awkward to word I guess.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle: I have updated my answer. See if that works for you :).